# Want to add JAX-RS Security

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jax-rs

I have developed a simple REST application using JAX-RS.

I want to add user authentication to my application (JAX-RS service).

How to implement authentication?

Answer (score 1):

May be [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/26/jax-rs-resteasy-basic-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial/) tutorial might help you.